# usage of memory stream

Tags: c#, memorystream

when will we use memory stream?

Comment: Whenever we need to. Can you please focus you question more? It is too broad for answering as it stands.

Comment: in which situations or for which type of results we use memory stream?

Answer (score 2):

`MemoryStream` is kind of wrapper over `byte[]` that implements stream. You need it when you have class that reads from `Stream` or writes to it, but you need to get/set raw bytes.

Comment: what are benefits or uses of memory stream over file stream?

Comment: @Cup Of Life you can't say that one has benefits over another, they are not equivalent. FileStream is for writing/reading files, MemoryStream is for `byte[]`